# JTabbedPane keeps adding new panels

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am trying to create a series of panels in JTabbedPane that displays a segment of info for the user. Right now, I am trying to get it so that the panel will refresh after the edit button is clicked. This button brings you to a different menu where you can adjust any of the fields and then go back to the tabbed pane. Unfortunately, while the object is changing by using the aforementioned menu, the pane does not reflect those changes correctly. What is does is make the first panel and all the tabs unclickable and seems to add a new panel to the bottom of the previous one with the new information. This occurs during the repaint() as previously it would not change at all.

```
JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();

    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();

    JPanel title = new JPanel();


    LayoutManager singleLine = new GridLayout(0,2);
    leftPanel.setLayout(singleLine);

    buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JLabel header = new JLabel("Basic Student Information");
    title.add(header);

    JLabel StreetLabel = new JLabel("First Name:             ");                //Creates all Labels
    JLabel LNLabel = new JLabel("Last Name:              ");
    JLabel IDLabel = new JLabel("Student ID:             ");
    JLabel GPALabel =new JLabel("GPA:                    ");


    JLabel StreetInfo = new JLabel(selectedStudent.getFirstName().toString());
    JLabel LNInfo = new JLabel(selectedStudent.getLastName().toString());
    JLabel IDInfo = new JLabel(selectedStudent.getID().toString());
    JLabel GPAInfo = new JLabel(selectedStudent.getGpa().toString());

    leftPanel.add(StreetLabel);
    leftPanel.add(StreetInfo);
    leftPanel.add(LNLabel);
    leftPanel.add(LNInfo);
    leftPanel.add(IDLabel);
    leftPanel.add(IDInfo);
    leftPanel.add(GPALabel);
    leftPanel.add(GPAInfo);

    StreetLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    LNLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    IDLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    GPALabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);

    JButton edit = new JButton("Edit");
    JButton close = new JButton("Close");
    buttons.add(edit);
    buttons.add(close);

    basicInfoTab.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    basicInfoTab.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    basicInfoTab.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    edit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            readMenu.setVisible(false);
            generalInfo();
        }
    });

    close.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you wish to exit     this student's record?") == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
                readMenu.setVisible(false);
                HomeScreen();
            }
        }
    });
```

Any help in getting this to refresh successfully would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough information in your code sample to illustrate the problem. When I have issues like this, I create a small program to test things out... I reduce my code to the simplest parts than gradually add in pieces. Usually the mistake I'm making becomes apparent when I do this.

Comment: The issue is that I am not sure what I am looking for in this case. I can only take a few things out of commission before the program stops working entirely